# Change events execution order using jQuery.live()

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="myplugin.js" />
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function() {
    alert('Hi');
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
  $('#mytable').myplugin();
 </script>

 <table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>

myplugin.js code

.....
return this.each(function(index, id) {
 $(id + ' tbody tr').live('click', function() {
  alert('Hello');
 });
});
.....
```

Under that circustances, the order of executiong would be:

```
alert('Hi');
alert('Hello');
```

but I want to be the inverse.
It's possible to change the execution order for this?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the prettiest way, but you could postpone your first call like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Hi');
    }, 0);
   });
  });
```

But maybe there's an "official" way as well...

Answer (score 0):

You should swap the order of the scripts.